# Java convert location coordinates into double for long and lat

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I've been making an mobile android application on android studio and I've got locations saved on the database. I need to convert these long and lats into a double so that it can be used in a google maps fragment.

At the moment it is getting the string from the database like this:

```
  Cursor res = dbHelper3.getEvent(journey, message);
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        showMessageData("Error", "No data");
        return;
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append(res.getString(1));

    }
```

but theres an issue with converting it into a double as both long and lat are saved as one big string. For example it will print:

"52.301293 0.185935"

When I try this

```
 String location = buffer.toString();
    locationText.setText(buffer.toString().trim());
    float f = Float.parseFloat(location);
```

it gives an error:

*This cannot be converted into a double as its two separate numbers* Is there a way of somehow separating these into two double numbers or do I have to redesign the way my database gets the location ?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert a string containing space into double, which will ultimately crash app.
You need to split your string ''location'' to two strings by space as:

```
String[] splited = location.split("\\s+");
```

Then you can covert it to double as below

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(splited[0]);

double longitude = Double.parseDouble(splited[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the latitude and longitude information separately like that:

```
String location = "52.301293 0.185935";

String[] afterSplitLoc = location.split(" ");
```

After that convert them to Double like that :

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(afterSplitLoc[0]);

double longitude = Double.parseDouble(afterSplitLoc[1]);
```

And than use on map. For example add a marker:

```
   private GoogleMap googleMap((MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.YOURMAPID)).getMap();

   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( latitude, -longitude)).title("Marker"));
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, unless you have special reason, you should save the latitude and longitude in separate columns, as it will make future update operation easier.

---

You can use split() method to separate the two values:

```
String location = "52.301293 0.185935"; 
String[] latlng = location.split(" ");
System.out.println("Lat = " +latlng[0]+" Longitude = "+latlng[1]);
//You will get sth like "Lat = 52.301293 Longitude = 0.185935"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
String location = buffer.toString().trim();
String[] latLon = location.split(" ");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(latLon[0]);
double lon = Double.parseDouble(latLon[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks kshetline,

worked perfect

```
 String string = buffer.toString();
    String[] parts = string.split(" ");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
    String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556

    locationText.setText(part1 + "\n" + part2);

    float longNum = Float.parseFloat(part1);
    float latNum = Float.parseFloat(part2);

    locationText.setText(longNum + "\n" + latNum);

    final LatLng eventLocation1 = new LatLng(longNum, latNum);
```